# Parse Objects in PowerShell to create PSCustom Object

Tags: powershell

I have written a PowerShell Function, which returns stuff like this (from `$Objekt.Columns`):

Example 1:

```
Addr.BoNumber        Addr.FullName
-------------        -------------
{212, 210, 211, 104} {xy, cv, bn, mm}
```

Example 2:

```
Addr.BoNumber        Addr.FullName
-------------        -------------
{212}                {xy}
```

Example 3:

```
Addr.BoNumber        Addr.FullName     Addr.Email
-------------        -------------     ----------
{212, 210, 211, 104} {xy, cv, bn, mm}  {x, y, z, n}
```

Now I'm trying to write a parser which changes this structure to this:

```
Addr.BoNumber        Addr.FullName
-------------        -------------
212                  xy
210                  cv
211                  bn
104                  mm
```

As you can see, I have either one or multiple Properties and either one or multiple values. `Addr.BoNumber[0]` belongs to `Addr.FullName[0]`, `Addr.BoNumber[1]` belongs to `Addr.FullName[1]` etc.

I have the following function which should parse it, but I have some issues saving the Values from `.Rows` to the `PSCustomObject` Properties.

This is my parsing function:

```
function New-OOPowerShellObject {

    Param ( 
        [Parameter( 
            Mandatory = $true, 
            Position = 0, 
            ValueFromPipeline = $true 
        )]
        [FlatResponseData]$Objekt 
    )

    # Return Objekt erstellen
    $ReturnObjekt = [PSCustomObject]@{}

    # Über Columns loopen und Titel eintragen
    $Objekt.Columns | % {
        Add-Member -InputObject $ReturnObjekt `
                   -NotePropertyName $_.Name `
                   -NotePropertyValue (foreach())
    }

    foreach($o in $Objekt.Columns)
    {
        $c = ($o.Rows.count) - 1
        0..$c | % {
            $ReturnObjekt."$($_.Name)" += $o.Rows[$_]
        }
    }

    # Return
    $ReturnObjekt
}
```

But i get this error (in german):

```
Ausnahme beim Festlegen von "": "Das Argument kann nicht verarbeitet werden, da der Wert des Arguments "name" ungültig ist. Ändern Sie den Wert des Arguments "name", und führen Sie den Vorgang erneut aus."
In Zeile:26 Zeichen:30
+             $ReturnObjekt."$($_.Name)" += $o.Rows[$_]
+                              ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

Any Ideas?

EDIT: Additional information:

- Everything is in: `$Objekt.Columns`
- Property titles are in: `$Objekt.Columns.Name` as a string
- Property values are in: `$Objekt.Columns.Rows` as an array

Comment: Why not just change the other function's output/

Comment: @Jacob Colvin because the other function is just a FlatDataRequest. I get the Data returned like this. and I will have a lot of similar functions, which will need to have parsing.

Comment: Numbers don't have a `Name` property...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I went for it:

```
function Format-OOFlatResponseData {

    Param ( 
        [Parameter( 
            Mandatory = $true, 
            Position = 0, 
            ValueFromPipeline = $true 
        )]
        [FlatResponseData]$Objekt 
    )
    # Process für Pipeline Input
    Process {

        # Über Rows loopen
        $RowCount = $Objekt.RowCount
        $Return = 0..($RowCount - 1) | foreach {

            # PSCustomObject erstellen
            $PSCust = [PSCustomObject]@{}
            foreach($C in $Objekt.Columns)
            {
                # Values zu PSCustomObject
                Add-Member -InputObject $PSCust `
                            -NotePropertyName $C.Name `
                            -NotePropertyValue $C.Rows[$_]
            }

            # Return PSCustomObject in Return Var
            $PSCust
        }

        # Return alles
        $Return
    }
}
```